# Using Microsoft Forms With SharePoint 2016 On Premise

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I want to know is it possible to add a Microsoft Forms Form into a SharePoint Enterprise 2016 On-premise site?

I searched in Google and the examples are all with SharePoint Online.

Please advise me on this.

Thanks and regards,
Chiranthaka

Comment: There is no webpart for for this, I think you can added the embedded link of the Forms on the Content / Script  Editor webpart

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Forms is an online survey, quizzes, and polls creator, available for Office 365 Education subscriber.

This feature is released in SharePoint Online, not available in On Premises.

You can check the Rouying Liang's reply in the blog below:

[image]

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Forms-Blog/SharePoint-web-part-powered-by-Microsoft-Forms/ba-p/109942

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Forms is only available for Office 365.However if you have Office 365 account,you can create Form in Office 365 and embed that in On-Prem Sharepoint using Script Editor

https://sharepointlibrarian.com/2018/03/26/embed-quizzes-and-or-results-in-sharepoint-using-microsoft-forms/